# Javascript export default and import

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const API1 = new API({
   ...
})

const API2 = new API({
   ...
})

export default { API1, API2 }
```

I need to import like this:

```
import API1 from '/lib/api'

API1.get()...
```

But it doesn't work.
I don't want to do this:

```
import blah from '/lib/api'
blah.API1.get()...
```

How can I solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: *I don't want to do this:* Can you explain why? I'm not understanding what exactly the problem is

Comment: Sorry. I would like to call just API1.get() instead of create a variable and call like this: import var from '/lib/api' var.API1.get()

Answer (score 0):

If you need to export multiple items, and don't want to have to create two variables in the consuming module (one for the default import - the object, and another for the `API1` property), your only other option is to change the default export to a named export, allowing you to import *just* one particular named property:

```
const API1 = new API({
   ...
})

const API2 = new API({
   ...
})

export { API1, API2 }
```

and

```
import { API1 } from '/lib/api'

API1.get()...
```

The `export {` syntax indicates that the export is named, rather than default, and the `import {` syntax indicates that you're importing a named import, rather than a default import.

(It looks a lot like destructuring, and it's a little bit similar, but it's not the same)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're default exporting an object you need to access individual property to access there methods, Instead you can use named exports

```
// exporting values

export const API1 = new API({
   ...
})

export const API2 = new API({
   ...
})
```

---

```
// Importing values

import { API1 } from '/lib/api'

API1.get()...
```